# count button clicks for dynamic generated button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

What is a simple way to count in C# how many times an asp net button has been clicked in the same page e.g page1.aspx? The counter should be valid per user and reset when I go to page2.aspx, then return back to page1.aspx. the counter should persist in case of reloading the same page.
the button is created dynamically in Page Init 
`Button x = new Button();`
I cannot use javascript. thanks

Comment: if you return back from page 2 to page1 then what happen to counter? do you want to retain the value of counter or reset it.

Comment: Can that be added in session?

Comment: U can use any one of session,hidden field, cache, view state, cookies, profile values

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for maintain hit counters

```
public static class Counter
{
       private static long hit;

       public static void HitCounter()
       {
          hit++;
       }

       public static long GetCounter()
       {
          return hit;
       }
}
```

Increment the value of counter at page load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Counter.HitCounter(); // call static function of static class Counter to      increment the counter value
}
```

the time you redirect the user you can make count as `null`

Comment: But static value can be alter by different user because it is shareable with all user

Comment: Hope that this will create issues since the Static variables have Application Scope

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan : but that will make messy for him that he should take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to use [session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx), it enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. So that you can access the value even when you returning from `page2.aspx`. the code for this will be

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Session["ClickCount"]!=null)
       Session["ClickCount"]=(int)Session["ClickCount"]++;
   else
       Session["ClickCount"]=0;
}
```

If you want to reset it when you leave the page means you can use:

```
 if(Session["ClickCount"]!=null)
       Session["ClickCount"]=0;
 // Redirect to page
```